# How Etherum Blockchain Smart Contract Stored

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

while I'm researching how the ethereum blockchain works. I have come across a problem.

usually blocks contain the transaction data. chaining those blocks will create a blockchain. I learned that ethereum smart contracts are also stored in the blockchain if the block contains the transaction data how does the smart contract stored in the blockchain.

also, I can't figure out the relationship between the ethereum blockchain and EVM.

Answer (score 1):

> if the block contains the transaction data how does the smart contract stored in the blockchain.

Thee code is stored in the payload of the contract deployment transaction.